# Keep old version of Firebase with CocoaPods

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods, firebase-authentication, firebase-remote-config

Firebase has updated to 4.0, with it breaking a lot of code, so I need to keep my installation at 3.x-ish. I've never done this before, so  with me, but I get errors like this:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/RemoteConfig (= 1.3.4)` required by `Podfile`
- `Firebase/RemoteConfig (= 1.3.4)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/RemoteConfig (= 1.3.4)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

This is the way I tried to freeze in my podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database', '3.1.2'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '3.1.1'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '1.3.4'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '1.2.3'
```

Btw I tried `pod repo update` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database', '<4'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '<4'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '<4'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '<4'
```

Comment: Right - the subspecs have the version of the Firebase pod, not the version of the particular dependent pod